# Error en la carga de la página cuando la base de datos está vacía

Tags: php, sql-server

Me sale el siguiente error al cargar la página y específicamente cuando la base de datos está vacía: "no conectado, error: Error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on bool in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\dashboard-typhoon\pages\plantilla.php:35 Stack trace: #0 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\dashboard-typhoon\controller\plantilla.controlador.php(5): include() #1 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\dashboard-typhoon\index.php(5): ControladorPlantilla->ctrTraerPlantilla() #2 {main}"
Me queda claro que si la base de datos está vacía, el procedimiento almacenado que trae los datos a la vista pues no puede ejecutar el fetchAll(), el procedimiento almacenado que ocupo en PHP para recuperar los datos de la base de datos es este:

```
      $salaryAnalysis ="EXEC Get_Salary_Analysis_by_HC_Full 0,'".$user."'";
      $bygen = $conn->query($salaryAnalysis);
      $data = $bygen->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

El procedimiento almacenado es en SQL Server y es el siguiente:

```
SELECT nullif(tbl_Niv.[nivel],0),nullif(tbl_Budget.HC_B,0) AS HC_B,nullif(tbl_Budget.Amount_B,0) AS Amount_B,nullif(tbl_Budget.Average_B,0) AS Average_B
                                            ,Actuales_tbl_Temp.nivel,Actuales_tbl_Temp.HC_Actuals,Actuales_tbl_Temp.Amount_Actuals,Actuales_tbl_Temp.Average_Actuals
                                            ,isnull(tbl_Budget.HC_B,0)-Actuales_tbl_Temp.HC_Actuals AS HC_Var
                                            ,isnull(tbl_Budget.Amount_B,0)-Actuales_tbl_Temp.Amount_Actuals as Amount_Var_moneda
                                            ,((isnull(tbl_Budget.HC_B,0)-Actuales_tbl_Temp.HC_Actuals)*isnull(tbl_Budget.Average_B,0))*',@No_Periods,' AS Due_HC_var
                                            ,((isnull(tbl_Budget.Average_B,0)-Actuales_tbl_Temp.Average_Actuals)*Actuales_tbl_Temp.HC_Actuals)*',@No_Periods,' AS Due_MRP_Var
                                            ,isnull((isnull(tbl_Budget.Average_B,0)-Actuales_tbl_Temp.Average_Actuals)/nullif(isnull(tbl_Budget.Average_B,0),0),0) AS Avg_Var
                                            ,isnull((isnull(tbl_Budget.Amount_B,0)-Actuales_tbl_Temp.Amount_Actuals)/nullif(isnull(tbl_Budget.Amount_B,0),0),0) AS Amount_Var_porcentaje
                                    FROM [ty_nivel_budget] tbl_Niv
```

Es muy largo por eso solo pongo una parte y también por cuestiones de confidencialidad.

Ahora, mi pregunta concretamente es, cómo puedo hacer que las columnas que muestro en vez de que le envien el error al fetchAll(), le envién ceros cuando está vacía la base de datos??? Le puse los isnull pero no funcionó. Alguien me puede ayudar con alguna sugerencia???

Comment: Puedes controlar el error mediante try catch y generar el array con los valores que espera recibir en el catch.

Comment: @estrano3 Gracias, tu consejo me fue muy útil en el catch pude manejar los valores ya vacíos.